# Path From Positive Dedekind Cuts to Reals?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, real-numbers

Don't spend a lot of time on this. I'm certain I could bang it out myself; but maybe there's an answer out there that someone already knows.

Say we use Dedekind cuts to construct the reals. Addition is fine and the proof that a set bounded above has a supremum is just lovely. Then we get to defining multiplication and all hell breaks loose - not that there's anything deep or really difficult about it, but at the very least the elegance is lost in a mass of special  cases.

So I say to myself this is just because of the historical accident that people figured out how to extend the positive rationals to the rationals before considering completeness; why not  get completeness first?

So the plan is to use Dedekind cuts of *positive* rationals to construct the *positive* reals, and then go from there to the reals. (In all of this "positive" may mean strictly positive or non-negative, whatever works.)

This leads to at least one **question**: For what values of *whatever* and *the construction* can one prove the following theorem?

**Theorem** If $F$ is an ordered field then the set of positive elements is a *whatever*. Conversely, given a *whatever* $P$, *the construction* gives an ordered field $F$ such that $P$ is (isomorphic to) the set of positive elements of $F$.

Or if there is no such general theorem we could be more specific. Say $P$ is the set of positive reals. I can think of at least two constructions that do in fact lead from $P$ to $\Bbb R$; the **question** is what do I need to prove about $P$ in order to prove that the result is in fact $\Bbb R$.

One construction would be to say that a real is just an element of $P$ with a plus or minus sign attached. This seems likely to lead to the sort of special-casing that we're trying to avoid (already when we think about $0$ we see we need to add a special clause to the effect that $+0=-0$; blech).

Another construction is to regard $(a,b)\in P^2$ as representing the real $a-b$. So we'd define $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if $a+d=c+b$, we'd define the sum and product of elements of $P^2$ in the obvious way (in particular $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac+bd,ad+bc)$), show these operations lift to the quotient $P^2/\sim$ and be on our way.

I kind of like the second construction. What do I need to prove about $P$ to show that $P^2/\sim$ is an ordered field with positive cone $P$?

Comment: ??? Would be nice if people commented on the reason for downvotes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This falls out from the the definition of a field and the requirement that $P$ embeds in the "group of differences" (your $P^2/\sim$). It will amount to saying that $P$ must be a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) whose additive semigroup satisfies the cancellation law, *if $x + y = x + z$, then $y = z$*, and whose multiplicative semigroup is a group.

By the way, did you know that any densely and completely ordered commutative group   is isomorphic to the reals? This leads to a little-known but very neat way of defining multiplication by studying the order-preserving homomorphisms of the additive group. I find this a far more satisfactory way of avoiding all those case splits.

Comment: You need some additional hypothesis (maybe densely ordered) in your second paragraph, to rule out $\mathbb{Z}$.  To classify homomorphisms, it also seems to me that you would need a stronger result (e.g., that the isomorphism in question is unique once you determine its value on a single element).

Comment: $P$ here is the set of positive reals, and I am assuming David has already shown it's the positive cone of a completely ordered commutative group. I agree that to get David's propose theorem to stand without that assumption you need to say more.

Comment: I'm just saying that it certainly isn't true that any completely ordered commutative group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @RobArthan Very interesting. The first paragraph is the sort of thing I was asking for, but yes the second paragraph may well be much nicer. If we just want to construct $\Bbb R$ we don't need the general theorem about ordered groups. We've constructed the reals as Dedekind cuts, defined $+$ and $<$ and shown that $(\Bbb R, +, <)$ is a complete ordered group. Now say $M$ is the class of homomorphisms from $\Bbb R$ to itself which are either increasing, decreasing or constant. There's a natural map from $M$ to $\Bbb R$ given by $\phi\mapsto\phi(1)$. I suspect the tricky part is [continued]

Comment: @RobArthan [continued] showing this map is a bijection. Then $M=\{\phi_x:x\in\Bbb R\}$, where $\phi_x(1)=x$. We define multiplication by saying $\phi_{xy}=\phi_x\phi_y$ and yes it seems likely that things then work out very nicely. Thanks.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for the comment, but there's no need to worry - I'm not going to blindly believe the details of what he said, going to take it as a big hint and work things out. Seems like he may well be right that it's the nice way to do all this...

Comment: @EricWofsey: thanks. I forgot to include the condition that the order should be dense in the second part of my answer. I have done that now.

Answer (score 2):

Rather that define dedekind cuts on the set of rational numbers, in a natural way we can modify the definition and define cuts on the positive rational numbers. In this new setting, we construct the non-negative real numbers, $\mathbb R^{\ge0}$, and we can show it forms a commutative semifield, and we don't get bogged down in checking, ad nauseum, the case-by-case breakdown for multiplication.

In exactly the same way as we the integers are constructed from the natural numbers found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction), we can get the negative real numbers from $\mathbb R^{\ge0}$, giving us the set of all real numbers. Using the $\mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb Z$ theory, it will be a ring.

Proposition: Every nonzero real number $x$ has a multiplicative inverse.
Proof
If the pair $(u,v)$ with $u,v \in \mathbb R^{\ge0}$  represents $x$, then $u \ne v$.
Recall the definition of multiplication:

$\quad {\displaystyle [(a,b)]\cdot [(c,d)]:=[(ac+bd,ad+bc)]}$

If $u \lt v$, then the number (block) represented by $(0, \frac{1}{v-u})$ is the inverse of $x$.

If $u \gt v$, then the number (block) represented by $(\frac{1}{u-v},0)$ is the inverse of $x$.

So every nonzero element of $\mathbb R$ has a multiplicative inverse and so we have actually constructed a field of numbers. $\quad \blacksquare$